# Could the union of a set of rational numbers and an open set be close?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a close set in the plane and $G$ be an open set in the plane. Denote $C$ by the set of rational points in the plane.
Prove that $F-C=G-C$ if and only if $F-C$ and $G-C$ are both empty or $R^{2}-C$.
I'm stuck in the stage that I have to prove the union of a set of rational numbers and an open set can't be close. But I don't know how to prove. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The union of an open set and a set of rational points in the plane can be closed. Take $G=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and $H=\{(0,0)\}$. Then $G\cup H=\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be closed, $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open, and assume that $F-\mathbb{Q}^2=G-\mathbb{Q}^2\notin \{\varnothing, \mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{Q}^2\}$.

Let's show that $F\supset \overline{G}$. If $x\in \overline{G}$, then for any $r>0$, the open disk $D$ around $x$ of radius $r$ intersects $G$. Since $D\cap G$ is non-empty and open, it is uncountable, so $$D\cap F\supset D\cap (F-\mathbb{Q}^2)=D\cap (G-\mathbb{Q}^2)\neq\varnothing.$$ From this it follows that if $\overline{G}=\mathbb{R}^2$, then $F=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $F-\mathbb{Q}^2=\mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{Q}^2$. By contraposition, it must be the case that $\overline{G}\neq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that $G\neq \varnothing$, otherwise $G\setminus \mathbb{Q}^2=\varnothing$. So $\varnothing\subsetneq G\subsetneq \overline{G}\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $\partial G$ denote the boundary of $G$. That is, $\partial G=\overline{G}\setminus G$. I claim that $\partial G$ must be uncountable. For this, we first note that $G\notin \{\varnothing\cup \mathbb{R}^2\}$, otherwise $G-\mathbb{Q}^2\in \{\varnothing, \mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{Q}^2\}$. To see this, fix $x\in G$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{G}$. There exists a radius $r>0$ such that the open disk $D_x$ of radius $r$ centered at $x$ is contained in $G$ and the open disk $D_y$ of radius $r$ centered at $y$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{G}$.

Let $u=y-x$ and let $v$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $u$. For each fixed $-r<s<r$, the line segment $L_s=\{x+sv+tu:t\in [0,1]\}$ starts at $x+sv\in G$ and ends at $y+sv\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{G}$, so there exists $t_s\in [0,1]$ such that $x+sv+t_su\in \partial G$. To see this, we note that by openness of $G$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{G}$, the sets $$U=\{t\in [0,1]:x+sv+tu\in G\},$$ $$V=\{t\in [0,1]:x+sv+tu\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{G}\}$$ are open, disjoint, and non-empty, and one can check that any $t_s\in [0,1]\setminus (U\cup V)$ will do the trick. Therefore each line segment $L_s$ intersects the boundary at some point $z_s$. Since the line segments $L_s$ are disjoint for distinct $s\in (-r,r)$, the points $(z_s)_{-r<s<r}$ are uncountably many points in $\partial G$, which is therefore uncountable.

Since $\partial G$ is uncountable, $\partial G-\mathbb{Q}^2$ is non-empty. Fix $a\in \partial G-\mathbb{Q}^2$. Since $G$ is open. Since $G$ is open, $\partial G\cap G=\varnothing$, and $a\notin G$, so $a\notin G-\mathbb{Q}^2$. We will show that $a\in F-\mathbb{Q}^2$, which will be a contradiction. Since we already know $a\notin \mathbb{Q}^2$, it is sufficient to show that $a\in F$.  But we already know $F\supset \overline{G}\ni a$, so we're done.